# Ruby on rails - Get and Pass js values and send/add as rails variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my applications `show.js.erb`, I added a `method` from `helper` that send some details to database when that files is loaded *(ps: `show.js.erb` file is loaded on publishers website)*.

This is `function` I have added in my helper:

```
<%= save_param(publisher_id, params['url'], params['price']) %>
```

`params['url']`& `params['price']` are both `params` from `js` file and are giving *automatically*.

My problem now is since `params['url']`& `params['price']` are `js` params, I can't pass them to my `save_param` function.

How can I pass `values` of `params['url']`& `params['price']` to my `save_param` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function instead of rails helper method on document ready.

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST', 
   url: '../save_param', 
   data: $.param({ publisher_id:1, url: params['url'], price: params['price'] })
});
```

you can initialize javascript variable with ruby variable if needed.

`var javascript_var = <%=ruby_var%>;`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @satendra. It doesn't `Post` and add the params to `.txt` file I wanted. I even hardcoded the path and still nothing.